# Abandoned transaction with low fee and now can't get any transactions to confirm

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

thanks for taking the time to help.

I tried to move btc from my Bitcoin Core wallet to my Electrum wallet and thinking that I was in no hurry tried sending it with the minimum transaction fee. After several days with no confirmations, I found out that was a stupid idea as the transaction is sitting in purgatory while all others with higher fees are moving ahead of mine. Lesson learned.

I tried using abandontransaction to clear it and didn't have any success. Then I tried loading Bitcoin Core using zapwallettxes command and got it to clear and the coins were back in my wallet. I attempted to transfer to my Electrum wallet about 1 hour later only to find the transaction back in the history but still 0 confirmations. 
I tried using zapwallettxes and reloading with the same results but created a transfer to my Electrum wallet as soon as it was finished loading, this time making the transaction fee the fastest available. It has now been over 24 hours and still I have 0 confirmations on the new transaction. 
What am I missing here? I'm far from an expert at this, but do have some basic knowledge and can follow any directions given. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but have you tried setting the transaction to "abandoned" ? 
Also disabling the wallet broadcasting in the meanwhile?

You can check this two links on how to recover a wrong transaction and how to do a proper full rbf

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fee_bumping#I_sent_the_stuck_transaction

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1802212.0

( i am aware that by this time either the transaction is forgotten or confirmed  but there would be more people that needs this answer (in fact that's how i got here))

Comment: The asker states "I tried using abandontransaction to clear it and didn't have any success."

Comment: Follow the steps on those links. 
For me, it didn't allowed me to mark as abandoned until i disabled the wallet connection.

Also if the transaction hasn't been accepted _yet_ you can still do an *rbf*.

As soon as i tried the rbf my transaction got accepted (so be aware of that too).